# Confidence interval graph in ggplot: how to make it more clearer?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have continuous data (spectra) and I would like to determine the significance of the differences. I tried to do it using confidence intervals in r, ggplot.
Here is the code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = df$wn, y = df$value)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = df$wn, y = df$value, colour = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = df$wn, ymin = df$lower, ymax = df$upper, fill = group))
```

I have around 15 spectra and the graph looks indistinguishable:

[image]

How could I make it clearer?

Comment: at the very least, use transparency, try `alpha = 0.3` for the ribbon layer. Using better colors might help too, but 15 is a lot to distinguish by color alone.

Comment: Maybe use `facet_wrap`. Note, you don't need the `df$` inside the `aes` and sometimes this will cause problems

Comment: Just to be clear, you can rewrite this as `ggplot(df, aes(x = wn, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = group))`

Comment: @RichardTelford With face_wrap I don't see where the confidence intervals overlap, and that's the point of the graph.